# little confusion regarding C++ pointers and this powerpoint slide

Tags: c++

[image: Image from a video, courtesy of ReelLearning]

In the above powerpoint slide, why is it that:

```
int* p = &x; 
cout << *p << endl;
```

outputs 25? From the little understanding that I have with pointers, &x is the address of x, which is assigned to *p, the value of p. In that case, since &x is 0003, so shouldn't *p and its output also be 0003?

For all the advanced coders out there who cannot stand a simpleton like myself, I apologize in 'advance'.

Comment: p is of type "int*", so the address is assigned to p.

Comment: @zycoactivtheory You don't need to apologize for beeing learning but, please, edit the code and make it a complete, self-standing example. (If output is 25 this is either not reproducible or there is code missing.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> &x is the address of x, which is assigned to *p

No, there is nothing assigned to `*p`.
In that line `p` is defined with type `int*` and `p` is assigned the address of `x`.

Now `p` holds the address 0003 and `*p` holds 25.

The `*` only relates to the variable definition in that line. During initialization you assign values to the variable you define.
If that wasn't the case, where should `p` point to in first place? Into which location should the 0003 be written then?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! One more question, what is the difference between int and int* ? As in, what does the pointer do to make that difference, if there is any?

Answer (score 1):

The slide is confusing, since it suggests that the name of the pointer variable were `*p`. The name of the variable is just `p`.

When you print the expression `p`, you will get `0003`, since that is the value of the pointer.

So the pointer points to the object at address `0003`, and the expression `*p` gets you the value from there, which is 25.

The slide should better say that cell 0001 has the name `p`. And that cell 0003 has two names (or paths to get there), which are `x` directly or `*p` indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

When we declare pointer we use `*` with datatype for e.g `int *p` it doesn't mean that we are declaring as well as referring to value at the same time.

So when you type
`int *p = &x;`
it is similar as writing

```
int *p;
p = &x;
```

Now **p** is **0003** and value at address **0003** is **25**. which you can get by ***p**.

Answer (score 0):

The **reference operator(&)** refers to the address of variable **x**,which is assigned to **p**.Since p is holding the address of a memory location it is of **pointer type (int*)**.Now the (*p) ,where (*) is the **deference operator(*)** refers to the value that the address in p is holding.